# Angular 6 Role based Authentication

Tags: angular, angular6

I have 5 modules in my project. roll access to these modules in create, update, delete and view access based on rolls.

How I create UI in angular 6 and I need the role when user login to the app and setting the role in shared service. for example admin roll access all the services and employee role only view the list not access to create and delete. I'm new to entering in angular.

Please help me any codes or examples in Roll based authentication

Comment: Are you getting these roles from backend?i.e when user logs in you must be getting role from the response?

Comment: yes sir. i am getting these roles from backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many different approaches you can follow but the basic idea behind restricting routes based on a certain condition by using `route-guards`.

in your case, you can have routes which load your modules lazily when `route-guard` authorize to use it and further nested routes loaded same way.

Decide your routes module.

```
{
   path:'/dashboard',
   loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule'
   canActivate:[ModuleRouteGuard],
   data: {
      accessRoles: ['Manager','HR']
   }
}
```

LazyModule_Routes.ts

```
{
   path:'/board',
   component: ManagerBoard
   canActivate:[ChildRouteGuard],
   data: {
      accessRoles: ['Manager']
   },
   resolve: {
      userRoles: 'userRolesResolver'  //use this resolver service to get data inside component so to decide if user can read/write . OR you can also use activatedRoutes data
   }
}
```

Route-Gaurd.ts

```
@Injectable()
class ModuleRouteGuard implements CanActivate { (1)
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}; (2)

  canActivate() {
    console.log("OnlyLoggedInUsers");
    if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()) { (3)
      return true;
    } else {
      window.alert("You don't have permission to view this page"); (4)
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

your app resolver which brings user roles from the server.

```
@Injectable()
class UserRolesResolver implements Resolve<Team> {
  constructor(private backend: Backend) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    //return this.backend.fetchTeam(route.params.id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create different component and render the component conditionally.
Consider your example. For that I create 2 component
1. view component
2. Create component.

like consider the codes

```
<div>
   <button *ngIf="usertype!=='employeee">Delete</button> <!--show delete button if user is not employee-->
   <create *ngIf="usertype!=='employeee"></create> <!-- Show create component if usertype is not emplyee -->
   <view [data]="data"></view> <!-- view for all type of user-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any way you are going to give specific button for create, update, delete and view after creating button you are going to enable or disable button programmatically correct .If this is your need means follow the below steps

create button with [disabled] option for ex.,

```
<button text="click" [disabled]="isAuthorised">Create</button>

<button text="click" [disabled]="isAuthorised">Delete</button>
```

Here isAuthorised is the variable which is in typescript make the variable as boolean(true / false) based on user role.it will enable or disable button accordingly