# Can we dynamically assign permissions to certain roles in angular?

Tags: angular6, access-control

I'm new to angular and am now developing a role management dashboard where a super-admin can assign and manage roles(possible roles: 'school admin', 'Teacher', 'Student', 'Parent') and their permissions respectively by clicking the check boxes.

NOTE: Refer the image for role management dashboard. [image: simple role management dashboard]

I found this link "https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/22/angular-7-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example" to be helpful when I tested to assign the permissions to the roles statically.

I also went through this question "[Angular 6 Role based Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55915007/angular-6-role-based-authentication)", but again the answer for this only helps with static role assignment.

so when a user clicks on the check box, the user should be assigned access to that particular component. I'm wondering is there a way where am user can manage roles and their permissions dynamically from an UI like Angular?If yes, how do we do it? Or any links that relates this would be of great help !!

Comment: Where's the issue? you save the roles in DB/backend somewhere... the angular UI is used to change the component visibility which is updated on the DB/backend... When the users who occupy these roles sign-in, you check the whether that user access to a component and then shows/hides those particular components

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806260/how-to-assign-dynamically-components-fields-permissions-to-certain-roles-in-angu/56856796#56856796

Comment: @DavidBrossard. the link you posted had hard-coded role assignment. but what i want here is, the admin could choose who can access what

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be creating a permission based application and make the user choose which permissions are assigned to which role.
e.g. https://betterprogramming.pub/dealing-with-permissions-in-angular-and-ngrx-de0c9e77bd0f